# How to find the nearest Vector from a default Position?

Tags: c#, vector, directx

In my C# project I have an Vector3 Array. Now I want to find the nearest Vector3 from the camera position. The position of the camera is also an Vector3 object. How I can do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just subtract the vectors from each other to get the length of the Vectors (Magnitude)

```
Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(1,2,3);
Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(1,1,1);

Vector3 difference= new Vector3(v1.X - v2.X, v1.Y - v2.Y, v1.Z - v2.Z)

float distance = Math.Sqrt(
   Math.Pow(difference.x, 2f) +
   Math.Pow(difference.y, 2f) +
   Math.Pow(difference.z, 2f));
```

Then you can calculate the distance with taking the sqrt from the powers of the coordinates like above code does.

The extensionmethod if you'd like

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double Distance(this Vector3 source, Vector3 target)
    {
        var difference = new Vector3(source.X - target.X, source.Y - target.Y, source.Z - target.Z);

        var distance = Math.Sqrt(
                Math.Pow(difference.X, 2f) +
                Math.Pow(difference.Y, 2f) +
                Math.Pow(difference.Z, 2f)
            );

        return distance;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it works because I wrote it in notepad++ :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Vector3.Distance(camera, otherObject) in a loop, keep the lowest distance object in a temporary variable i.e.

```
long closestDistance = -1;
Vector3 closestVector = null;

for(Vector3 otherVector : myCollection)
{
    long thisDistance = Vector3.Distance(camera, otherVector);

    if (thisDistance < closestDistance || closestDistance == -1)
    {
       closestDistance = thisDistance;
       closestVector = otherVector;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to create an Extension method for that. If it is not already there